# Compilinig error on WSL when I try to compile a C sourcefile with command line parameters

Tags: c, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The compiler fails when compiling the C code below, throwing stray character errors:

```
#include "stdio.h"  
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     int count;  
     printf("The command line has %d arguments:\n", argc - 1);  
     for(count = 1; count < argc; count++) {  
       printf("%d: %s\n", count, argv[count]);  
      }  
      printf("\n");  
 
      return 0;  
}
```

Compiler: gcc 5.4.0 20160609 Ubuntu 16.04.3

Screenshot of the error: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7c2Q.png)

By the way, other C files (like "hello world") can be successfully compiled.

Comment: There is no error in your code. What error do you see on wsl? (presuming Ubuntu default install) Are you using something like `gcc -Wall -Wextra -O3 -std=gnu11 -o nameforexe nameofsource.c`?  A minimal compile to the standard `a.out` would be `gcc -Wall -Wextra filename.c`

Comment: Based on the errors shown in your link it looks like your program file has non-ASCII bytes in it (it seems that some of the white space characters are no ASCII space or tab characters).  Use a programmer's text editor to construct your source file - do not use a word processor like Microsoft Word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, "*There are no errors in your code*", so any error you receive is either due to your compile string **OR** is due to you having edited the file in a windows editor that has corrupted the file within WSL.

To compile your code (without warning or error) to the default `a.out` executable, you can use a simple command line of:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra yourfilename.c
```

**note:** always compile with *warnings enabled*, at minimum `-Wall -Wextra`. You can add many more individual warning options as well as adding `-pedantic` which will enable a few more.

If you want to add a few additional options, the optimization level and the C-standard to compile against, as well as providing a custom name for your executable instead of the default `a.out`, you can use:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -O3 -o yourexename yourfilename.c
```

Give both a try and report back with the exact error (if any) you receive by editing your question and adding the exact text of the error you receive to your question.

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Thanks for your help! And I'm sorry about my question not clear or accurate.In fact I truely edit my code by notepad++,and I put my code in other disk together with my other codes compiled in Windows , for arranging them conveniently. Today I use vim to write it agian,and it works.

Comment: Could you please explain this specificly? I'll really appreciate it if you could give a hand or give some advice!

Comment: WSL files are stored with Linux File Permission (e.g. `drwxrwxrwx`). You can reach the WSL files from windows through `%AppData%\Local\lxss\...` If you have edited the files with notepad++ by using the path through `...\lxss\...` and then clicked 'save', you have corrupted that file in WSL because saving from windows does not preserve "Linux File Permission" information. You can copy from WSL through `...\lxss\...` to say `c:\users\you\documents` and edit with notepad++, but you must copy back **from within WSL** with, e.g. `cp /mnt/c/users/you/documents/file.c file.c` preserving perms.

Comment: Your error screenshot shows you most likely have windows UTF-16 chars in your file. Linux uses UTF-8. Save the file with the proper character set and it will compile fine (as long as your don't lose the Linux file permissions). Also for editing in WSL, install `vim` (`sudo apt-get install vim`) and spend the 30 minutes it takes to be able to move around and edit (`i` to enter *Insert mode*, `[esc]` to return to *Command mode*) and you never have to worry about the filesystem problems again `:)`